# Find the marginal pdfs for X and Y respectively

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[Question is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Zug.png)

> Suppose random variables, $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf given by: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}6x^2y &:&0\leq x\leq y\leq x+y\leq 2\\[1ex]\hspace{4ex}0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> (a) Find the marginal pdf for $X$ and $Y$, respectfully.  Do either of these marginal distributions look like a distribution discussed in this course?  If so, name the distribution and give its parameter(s).
>
> (b) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?  Use the marginal pdf to justify your answer.
>
> (c) Can you determine if $X$ and $Y$ are independent by only inspecting the joint probability density function?  Explain your reasons.  *Hint: Look at the supported region.*

Please help me solve this question I'm confused on how to find the integral domains when solving for marginal pdfs or otherwise as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0\leq x+y\leq 2 \Rightarrow -x\leq y\leq 2-x $$
$$...\Rightarrow-y\leq x\leq 2-y$$
We know that $0\leq x\leq y$ must also be true; hence we arrive at
$$0\leq x\leq y\leq 2-x,0\leq x(\leq 2-y\,\text{or} \leq y)$$
For the case of $f_Y(y)$, the upper bound of the integral changes between $0\leq y\leq1$ and $1\leq y\leq 2$, former being $y$ and the latter being $2-y$.
[Here is the visualization of the boundaries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th4Yr.png)
These boundaries then can be used to construct integrals for marginal probability density functions.
$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy}=\int_{x}^{2-x} {6x^{2}y\,dy},  0\leq x \leq 1$$
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx}=
\begin{cases}
 \int_{0}^{y} {6x^{2}y\,dx} & 0\leq y\leq 1\\
 \int_{0}^{2-y} {6x^{2}y\,dx}&1<y\leq 2
\end{cases}, 0\leq y \leq 2
$$

$f_X(x)=0$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ when $(x,y)$ is outside of the triangular boundary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had a question tho, for the marginal pdf of Y, for 0 < y < 1, the integration will go from x=0 to x=y, which is correct, but for 1 < y < 2, I don't get it why are you integration from 0 to 2-y? Shouldn't it be from 1 to 2-y?

Comment: @KrishThakur  $0\leq x\leq y\leq 2-x$ and $1\leq y\leq 2$ means $0\leq x\leq 2-y$, $$0\leq y\leq 2, 0\leq x\leq\min[y,2-y]\implies\begin{cases}0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\leq 2-y\leq 2\\\text{or}\\0\leq x\leq 2-y\lt 1\lt y\leq 2\end{cases}$$